# Can switch statements cause a 'Query is too Complex' error in MS Access 365?

Tags: sql, ms-access

As background, we are currently using Lotus Approach as our job schedule database.  Out of fear that one day it'll cease working with newer versions of Windows, I've been searching for an alternative that isn't terribly dissimilar from Approach.  One of the features in Approach that has been wonderful is that calculated fields are stored in the front end and has full access to all tables in the database, as well as other calculated fields without having to link them to forms, reports, or each other.  I have yet to find a program that handles calculated fields in a similar manner, so I've moved to using queries in Access to beginning building these calculated fields (around 200 formulas).

That said, I have 4 tables and 3 queries, but I'm hitting a wall with one of the queries.  In the query that's giving me the error, I think I've determined the problem has to do with 1 switch statement (AUDIT_JTD_EARNED_REV) as there are 3 other formulas that rely on this calculation and if I delete one of these (not all of them), then the query will run.

I have not used Access before in any meaningful way, so if there is a better way of doing it, then I'm all ears.  Below are the 3 queries I'm using and the error is occurring in the Audit Calc query.

**Audit Calc**

```
SELECT Book.job_id,
(
Book.jtd_ti_cost - Book.audit_jtd_ti_cost + Book.jtd_eq_credit + Book.sdp_profit )       AS AUDIT_FCST_PROFIT_ADJ,
Book.book_jtd_cost - audit_fcst_profit_adj + ICalc.ic_audit_jtd_profit_adj
AS
AUDIT_JTD_COST,
Switch(Book.stat_cd = 'C', Book.jtd_gross_bill + Book.accrued_billing,
( Book.stat_cd = 'I'
AND
audit_jtd_cost + audit_fcst_profit >
Book.book_contract_amt * audit_pct_cmpl )
                                                                 OR (
Book.stat_cd = 'A'
AND Book.job_type <> '2'
AND audit_pct_cmpl >= 0.2 ), Round(Book.book_contract_amt * audit_pct_cmpl, 2),
Book.stat_cd = 'A'
AND Book.job_type = '1'
AND audit_pct_cmpl < 0.2, audit_jtd_cost, true,
audit_jtd_cost + audit_fcst_profit)
AS AUDIT_JTD_EARNED_REV,
Book.book_contract_amt - audit_fcst_profit
AS AUDIT_FCST_COST,
Switch(Book.book_contract_amt < 1, 1, Book.job_type = 2,
Book.jtd_gross_bill - Book.accrued_billing / Book.book_contract_amt, true,
audit_jtd_cost / audit_fcst_cost)
AS AUDIT_PCT_CMPL,
Nz(Book.fcst_job_profit)
+ audit_fcst_profit_adj
+ Nz(ICalc.ic_audit_fcst_profit)
AS AUDIT_FCST_PROFIT,
Round(audit_jtd_earned_rev - Nz(Book.prior_adt_rev), 2)
AS AUDIT_YTD_EARNED_REV,
audit_jtd_cost + audit_addl_loss - Nz(Book.prior_adt_cost)
AS AUDIT_YTD_COST,
audit_ytd_earned_rev - audit_ytd_cost
AS AUDIT_YTD_EARNED_PROFIT,
Switch(Book.prime_job_id IS NULL
 OR ( Nz(Book.fcst_job_profit, 0) - Nz(ICBook.fcst_job_profit, 0) ) > 0
 OR Book.stat_cd <> 'A'
 OR
( Book.book_contract_amt - audit_fcst_cost ) >= 0, 0, true,
audit_fcst_profit - audit_jtd_cost + audit_jtd_earned_rev)
AS AUDIT_ADDL_LOSS,
Iif(Book.stat_cd <> "a", 0, audit_fcst_cost - audit_jtd_cost)
AS
AUDIT_FCST_COST_TO_CMPL,
audit_fcst_profit / Iif(Book.job_type = 2,
             Book.book_contract_amt, audit_fcst_cost)
AS AUDIT_PROFIT_PCT,
audit_jtd_earned_rev - audit_jtd_cost + audit_addl_loss
AS
AUDIT_JTD_EARNED_PROFIT,
audit_jtd_earned_rev - Book.jtd_gross_bill - Book.accrued_billing + Nz(Book.jtd_ret_amt) AS AUDIT_OVER_UNDER_BILLING
FROM   ([book calc] AS Book
 LEFT JOIN [book calc] AS ICBook
        ON Book.job_id = ICBook.prime_job_id)
LEFT JOIN [interco calc] AS ICalc
       ON Book.job_id = ICalc.prime_job_id;
```

**Interco Calc**

```
SELECT [book calc].prime_job_id
       AS PRIME_JOB_ID,
       [book calc].job_id
       AS SUB_JOB_ID,
       [book calc].jtd_ti_cost - [book calc].audit_jtd_ti_cost +
       [book calc].jtd_eq_credit + [book calc].sdp_profit
       AS IC_AUDIT_FCST_PROFIT_ADJ,
       [book calc].fcst_job_profit
       + ic_audit_fcst_profit_adj
       AS IC_AUDIT_FCST_PROFIT,
       Round([book calc].jtd_mat_cost
             + [book calc].jtd_sub_cost
             + [book calc].jtd_oth_cost
             + [book calc].jtd_gl_cost
             + [book calc].jtd_eq_cost
             + [book calc].jtd_labor_cost
             + [book calc].accrued_cost
             + Nz([book calc].prior_adt_ti)
             + [book calc].audit_ytd_ti_cost - Nz([book calc].prior_eq_credit) -
                   [book calc].ytd_eq_credit + [book calc].jtd_sdp_cost -
             [book calc].sdp_profit, 2)
       AS IC_AUDIT_JTD_COST,
       ic_audit_jtd_cost - ( [book calc].jtd_gross_bill
                             + [book calc].accrued_billing )
       AS IC_AUDIT_JTD_PROFIT_ADJ,
Iif([book calc].book_contract_amt < 1, 1,
Iif([book calc].job_type = 2, ( [book calc].gross_bill
                                + [book calc].accrued_billing ) /
                                          [book calc].book_contract_amt, ic_audit_jtd_cost / ic_audit_fcst_cost)) AS IC_AUDIT_PCT_CMPL,
[book calc].book_contract_amt - ic_audit_fcst_profit
       AS IC_AUDIT_FCST_COST
FROM   [book calc]
WHERE  ( [book calc].prime_job_id ) IS NOT NULL;
```

And finally **Book Calc**

```
SELECT fsjob.*,
       eq_aed.eq_aed_prem
       AS EQ_AED_PREM,
       eq_aed.eq_aed_chrg
       AS EQ_AED_CHRG,
       Nz(fsjob.gross_bill)
       + Nz(fsjob.prior_gross_bill)
       + Nz(fsjob.prior_accr_bill)
       AS JTD_GROSS_BILL,
       Round(Nz(fsjob.sc_cost) + Nz(fsjob.prior_sc_cost), 2)
       AS JTD_SUB_COST,
       Nz(fsjob.labor_cost)
       + Nz(fsjob.prior_labor_cost)
       AS JTD_LABOR_COST,
       Nz(fsjob.oth_cost)
       + Nz(fsjob.prior_oth_cost)
       AS JTD_OTH_COST,
       Nz(fsjob.mat_cost)
       + Nz(fsjob.prior_mat_cost)
       AS JTD_MAT_COST,
       Nz(fsjob.eq_cost) + Nz(fsjob.prior_eq_cost)
       AS JTD_EQ_COST,
       Nz(fsjob.gl_cost) + Nz(fsjob.prior_gl_cost)
       AS JTD_GL_COST,
       Nz(fsjob.ti_cost) + Nz(fsjob.prior_ti_cost)
       AS JTD_TI_COST,
       Iif(( fsjob.sdp_cd = 'SDP'
             AND fsjob.stat_cd = 'I' )
            OR ( fsjob.sdp_cd = 'SDP'
                 AND jtd_gross_bill > 0
                 AND fsjob.stat_cd = 'A'
                 AND jtd_sub_cost > 0 ), Round(variable.sdp_pct *
                                               Nz(fsjob.fcst_sc_cost), 2), 0)
       AS
       JTD_SDP_COST,
Switch(fsjob.stat_cd = 'I', Nz(fsjob.contract_amt, 0) - jtd_gross_bill, true, Nz(fsjob.accr_bill_adj, 0))
       AS ACCRUED_BILLING,
Switch(fsjob.stat_cd = 'C', jtd_gross_bill + accrued_billing, true, Nz(fsjob.contract_amt, 0))
       AS BOOK_CONTRACT_AMT,
Iif(fsjob.stat_cd = 'I', Round(
book_contract_amt - Nz(fsjob.fcst_job_profit)
- jtd_sub_cost + jtd_labor_cost + jtd_oth_cost + jtd_mat_cost + jtd_eq_cost + jtd_gl_cost + jtd_ti_cost + jtd_sdp_cost, 2), Nz(fsjob.accr_cost_adj))
       AS ACCRUED_COST,
Round(jtd_sub_cost + jtd_labor_cost + jtd_oth_cost
      + jtd_mat_cost + jtd_eq_cost + jtd_gl_cost
      + jtd_ti_cost + jtd_sdp_cost + accrued_cost, 2)
       AS BOOK_JTD_COST,
Round(book_contract_amt - Nz(fsjob.fcst_job_profit), 2)
       AS BOOK_FCST_COST,
Iif(fsjob.stat_cd = 'C'
     OR
book_contract_amt < 1, 1,
Iif(fsjob.job_type = 2, ( accrued_billing + jtd_gross_bill ) / book_contract_amt, book_jtd_cost / book_fcst_cost))
       AS BOOK_PCT_CMPL,
Iif(fsjob.stat_cd <> 'A', Round(jtd_gross_bill + accrued_billing, 2),
Iif(fsjob.job_type = 2,
Iif(( book_jtd_cost + Nz(fsjob.fcst_job_profit) ) < (
    book_contract_amt * book_pct_cmpl ),
Nz(fsjob.fcst_job_profit) + book_jtd_cost, Round(
book_pct_cmpl * book_contract_amt, 2)),
Iif(Nz(fsjob.fcst_job_profit) < 0, Nz(fsjob.fcst_job_profit) + book_jtd_cost, Iif(book_pct_cmpl < 0.195, book_jtd_cost,
Round(
                                    book_pct_cmpl * book_contract_amt, 2)))))
       AS
BOOK_JTD_EARNED_REV,
( book_jtd_earned_rev - book_jtd_cost )
       AS BOOK_JTD_PROFIT,
Iif(fsjob.stat_cd = 'C', book_jtd_profit, Nz(fsjob.fcst_job_profit))
       AS
BOOK_FCST_PROFIT,
( book_contract_amt - book_fcst_profit - book_jtd_cost )
       AS BOOK_COST_TO_CMPL,
( Nz(fsjob.prior_bk_rev) - Nz(fsjob.prior_bk_cost) )
       AS BOOK_PRIOR_PROFIT,
Round(book_jtd_cost - Nz(fsjob.prior_bk_cost), 2)
       AS BOOK_YTD_COST,
Round(book_jtd_earned_rev - Nz(fsjob.prior_bk_rev), 2)
       AS BOOK_YTD_EARNED_REV,
( book_ytd_earned_rev - book_ytd_cost )
       AS BOOK_YTD_PROFIT,
Iif(fsjob.stat_cd = 'C', 0, Nz(fsjob.fcst_ye_labor) - jtd_labor_cost)
       AS
LABOR_COST_TO_CMPL,
Round(jtd_gross_bill + accrued_billing - book_jtd_earned_rev, 2)
       AS
BOOK_EXCESS_BILLING,
Round(Iif(( fsjob.sdp_cd = 'SDP'
            AND fsjob.stat_cd = 'I' )
           OR ( fsjob.sdp_cd = 'SDP'
                AND Nz(jtd_gross_bill) > 0
                AND fsjob.stat_cd = 'A'
                AND
Nz(jtd_sub_cost) > 0 ), variable.sdp_pct * Nz(fsjob.fcst_sc_cost), 0), 2)
       AS
SDP_REV,
Round(Iif(fsjob.sdp_cd IS NOT NULL
          AND
fsjob.stat_cd <> 'C',
Iif(Nz(fsjob.fcst_sc_cost) > Nz(jtd_sub_cost),
                              Nz(fsjob.fcst_sc_cost) * variable.sdp_pct, Nz(jtd_sub_cost) * variable.sdp_pct), 0), 2)
       AS FCST_SDP_REV,
Round(Iif(fsjob.sdp_cd IS NOT NULL
          AND
fsjob.stat_cd <> 'C',
      Nz(fsjob.sc_cost) / variable.ytd_sdp_sub_cost * variable.ytd_sdp_exp, 0), 2)
       AS SDP_EXP,
( Nz(sdp.prior_cost) + Nz(sdp.curr_cost)
  + Nz(sdp.curr_ap) - Nz(sdp.prior_ap) + sdp_exp )
       AS JTD_SDP_EXP,
Iif(fsjob.sdp_cd <> 'SDP'
     OR fsjob.stat_cd = 'C', 0, Round(Nz(fsjob.fcst_sc_cost) - jtd_sub_cost, 2))
       AS SUB_COST_TO_CMPL,
fcst_sdp_rev - jtd_sdp_exp - fcst_sdp_addl_reserve_amt
       AS FCST_SDP_PROFIT,
sdp_rev - jtd_sdp_exp
       AS SDP_PROFIT,
Iif(book_pct_cmpl < 0.195, Round(( fcst_sdp_rev - jtd_sdp_exp ) * 0.5, 2), 0)
       AS
FCST_SDP_ADDL_RESERVE_AMT,
Iif(Nz(fsjob.fcst_job_profit) < 0, fcst_sdp_profit - Nz(fsjob.prior_sdp_credit), Iif(book_pct_cmpl < 0.195, 0,
Round(
book_pct_cmpl * fcst_sdp_profit - Nz(fsjob.prior_sdp_credit), 2)))
       AS
YTD_SDP_CREDIT,
Iif(fsjob.stat_cd = 'C', fcst_sdp_profit,
Iif(Nz(fsjob.fcst_job_profit) < 0, fcst_sdp_profit - Nz(fsjob.prior_sdp_credit),
Iif(Nz(fsjob.fcst_ye_pct_cmpl) < 0.195, 0,
                                                                                 Round(Nz(fsjob.fcst_ye_pct_cmpl) * fcst_sdp_profit - Nz(fsjob.prior_sdp_credit), 2)))) AS FCST_SDP_CREDIT,
sdp_profit - ytd_sdp_credit - Nz(fsjob.prior_sdp_credit)
       AS YTD_SDP_RESERVE_AMT,
ytd_sdp_credit + Nz(fsjob.prior_sdp_credit)
       AS JTD_SDP_CREDIT,
Round(Nz(eq_aed.eq_aed_chrg) / variable.ytd_eq_rev * variable.ytd_eq_profit, 2)
       AS YTD_EQ_CREDIT,
ytd_eq_credit + Nz(fsjob.prior_eq_credit)
       AS JTD_EQ_CREDIT,
Round(fsjob.ti_pct * Nz(fsjob.fcst_labor_cost), 2)
       AS FCST_TI_COST,
audit_ytd_ti_cost + Nz(fsjob.prior_adt_ti)
       AS AUDIT_JTD_TI_COST,
Switch(fsjob.ti_pct = 0.1, Nz(fsjob.ti_cost), true,
Round((jtd_labor_cost-Nz(fsjob.prior_labor_cost))*variable.actual_ti_pct, 2)
+ Nz(fsjob.wc_cost, 0))
       AS AUDIT_YTD_TI_COST
FROM   ((fsjob
         LEFT JOIN variable
                ON fsjob.var_ctrl_num = variable.var_ctrl_num)
        LEFT JOIN eq_aed
               ON fsjob.job_id = eq_aed.job_id)
       LEFT JOIN sdp
              ON fsjob.job_id = sdp.job_id;
```

The deepest nested IIF in all of these is only 3 deep and the most complex Switch statement only has 4 options.  And the fields used in these statements are not overly complex, either.  I've been fighting to simplify this for about a week and don't believe I can make it any more concise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reduce your query to a bare minimum to supply the main data and move all the calculations to a new query using the first as source.

Comment: That's what I've done.  The Book Calc query contains all the formulas that can be performed just on the tables or within the query itself.  This is the bulk of my formulas.  The Interco Calc query performs only a handful of arithmetic calculations (1 IIF statement).  The Audit Calc query is the one giving me fits and I have my From only referencing Book Calc (and an alias of Book Calc) and Interco Calc.  I think the issue is with the 1 formula I mentioned, but can't figure out why it's an issue.  I understood Switch functions didn't have limits, but even if it did, I think I'd still be safe.